# rust-gmp-kzen gmp bind problem : "dyld[...]: missing symbol called"

Tags: gcc, rust, gmp, bigint, abort

I am using rust-gmp-kzen library which bind rust to gmp. When I run the rust program, it aborts at the statement "BigInt::one();" which calls "__gmpz_init_set_ui" in it.
I reinstall gcc, gmp, rustup vs. however problem still occurs.

```
dyld[77446]: missing symbol called
```

I searched a lot on the internet but could not find any related solution. Can anyone any idea about this problem?

Comment: Is that the whole output of the compiler?

Comment: exactly. no stack, tree or any logs. I have detected the line which aborts by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Rustup and cargo uses arm64 arch. However gmp library is for x86_64 arch. Thus, when linking gmp library, rust cannot find the library and aborts.

I uninstall rustup :

`cargo self uninstall`

Then install again choosing x86_64-apple-darwin not arch64

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`